# Mysql get the latest row on join/select a table (1:n)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have the table "user" (Primary key is id) and the table "user_meta" (Primary key is user_id and valid_from).
The user table contains basic user data e.g. username, password, etc.
The user_meta contains possible changing data e.g. lastname, gender(yea its 2018 :D) etc.
So i have a history on which day which data are valid.

My Problem ist that i try to select all user with the currently valid data, but i failed often...

How i can select the correct data ?

For one user i can simply use

```
"select * from user_meta 
  JOIN user on user_meta.user_id = user.id 
  ORDER BY valid_from DESC LIMIT 1"
```

but how its working with multiple/all users?

greetings,
False

Comment: Please provide table structure for user_meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a join on a subselect for max_valid group by user

```
select * from user_meta
inner join (
    select user.id, max(user_meta.valid_from) max_valid
    from user_meta 
    JOIN user on user_meta.user_id = user.id 
    group by user.id
) t on t.id= user_meta.user_id and t.max_valid = user_meta.valid_from
```

or more simple

```
select * from user_meta
inner join (
    select user_meta.user_id, max(user_meta.valid_from) max_valid
    from user_meta 
    group by user_meta.user_id
) t on t.user_id= user_meta.user_id and t.max_valid = user_meta.valid_from
```

Comment: @scaisEdge I think, there is no need to join with user table in sub query.

Comment: @FahadAnjum  could be correct  .. is have added  also the query based  on your suggestion  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge 
Your Code works fine, but its not working e.g. if i try to get the meta data from a user post.
So i have to add a "Where user_meta.valid_from <= user_post.created" to get the user_meta from posted date.

Comment: I don't know how youy  last comment could be related  to the question you provided .. remember that we can't know your real need  .. we can just eval your question text  ..  ..hope that with your added where you retrive the values you need .

Comment: @scaisEdge
I also have the tables user, user_meta and user_posts, threads.
Now i try to get the valid user_meta, but its not working with my code

https://hastebin.com/jipuhayema.sql

Comment: @False  This seems not related  to your original question  .. you should post a new question with, clrarly described. with the code you are using,  a specific data sample  ..  your actual result  and your expected  result  .. when you have posted  the new query you can comment me the related  link  .. so i can eval you actual problem

Comment: @scaisEdge oh okay, i didnt opened a new thread because i thought its spam...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411316/mysql-id-from-query-in-subjquery

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
SELECT u.*, um.*
FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_meta um
    ON u.id = um.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(valid_from) AS max_valid_from
    FROM user_meta
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
    ON um.user_id = t.user_id AND
       um.valid_from = t.max_valid_from;
```

Not much to explain here, except that the subquery aliased as `t` will filter off all metadata records except for the latest one, for each user.